# Access list of items with list of indices

Tags: python, list, indexing

Consider a large list of named items (first line) returned from a large csv file (80 MB) with possible interrupted spacing

```
name_line =  ['a',,'b',,'c' .... ,,'cb','cc']
```

I am reading the remainder of the data in line by line and I only need to process data with a corresponding name. Data might look like

```
data_line =  ['10',,'.5',,'10289' .... ,,'16.7','0']
```

I tried it two ways. One is popping the empty columns from each line of the read

```
blnk_cols = [1,3, ... ,97]
while data:
    ...
    for index in blnk_cols: data_line.pop(index)
```

the other is compiling the items associated with a name from L1

```
good_cols = [0,2,4, ... ,98,99]   
while data:
    ...
    data_line = [data_line[index] for index in good_cols]
```

in the data I am using there will definitely be more good lines then bad lines although it might be as high as half and half.

I used the cProfile and pstats package to determine my weakest links in speed which suggested the pop was the current slowest item. I switched to the list comp and the time almost doubled.

I imagine one fast way would be to slice the array retrieving only good data, but this would be complicated for files with alternating blank and good data.

what I really need is to be able to do

```
data_line = data_line[good_cols]
```

effectively passing a list of indices into a list to get back those items. 
Right now my program is running in about 2.3 seconds for a 10 MB file and the pop accounts for about .3 seconds.

Is there a faster way to access certain locations in a list. In C it would just be de-referencing an array of pointers to the correct indices in the array.

Additions:
name_line in file before read

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,,,,,h,i,j,k,,,,l,m,n,
```

name_line after read and split(",")

```
['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','','','','','h','i','j','k','','','','l','m','n','\n']
```

Comment: What are you doing with data_line? Are you merely iterating it? Are you putting it into another datastructure?

Comment: Also, have you tried a generator?

Comment: "Consider a large list returned from a large csv file "?  Are you reading the **entire** file into one list?  Why?  Why not process each line individually?

Comment: the file I am reading is a higher frequency file (ie 10 hz). I am reading in the lines and accumulating and averaging all the values in the x second interval and writing this back into a file. ie go from 10 hz to 1 hz would accumulate 10 data values (from 0 to 1 seconds) average them and output the single data line into a file for the floor(time) of the averaged data range

Comment: I am processing each line individually. Editted that for clarity

Comment: Can you provide a more accurate example of the `name_line` list and a few examples of `data_line`? I'm wondering if the `name_line` list really looks like `['a','','b','','c' .... ,'','cb','cc']` i.e. with empty strings where you have double commas.

Comment: Does "I tried it two ways. One is popping the empty lines from each line of the read".  Mean "popping the empty **columns** from each line"?  If so, you might want to edit your question to use **column** when you mean column.  Why are you removing columns in the first place?  If it's slow, why do it?

Comment: Are you using `split(",")` to parse a CSV file?  What's wrong with the `csv` module which  handles much of this for you?

Comment: I was removing columns as it improved readability and simplified the code. Additionally I needed to write without the extra columns. If I use the indexing and load only the values I need into an array I imagine that might result in the speed bump I am looking for. I used split because each line is comma separated and the function looked like the perfect one for the job. Does using the csv module produce any speed benefit or return a better list than the split function?

Comment: Popping the columns appears to be faster than the indexing solution (at least using a generator) as creating the generator seems to be rather time intensive.

Comment: Replaced the generator with the corresponding for loop and got the benefit I expected (removing the pop time and giving a slight boost) for a total reduction of about .4 seconds

Answer (score 12):

Try a generator expression,

```
data_line = (data_line[i] for i in good_cols)
```

Also read here about 
[Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

as the top answer tells you: 'Basically, use a generator expression if all you're doing is iterating once'.

So you should benefit from this.

Comment: Which is faster rather depends on what you're doing with it. The advantage of a generator is that it's lazy, so you don't allocate a lot memory for items which you access just once.

Comment: @Marcin. Yes, clarified my answer.

Comment: Refactored all of my code to fit generator expressions. I go through each data line once to process (using a generator with appropriate indexing instead of popping the blank values initially). The code runs about .3 seconds slower because I need to recreate the generator expression for each data line.

Comment: @PaulSeeb I'm confused. *creating* the generator expression should not take any time.

Comment: there are 25000 lines in this file. I need to make a new generator for each line to process all the data in the line unless I can "reset" the generator for each line. I did some research on that and found that was impossible.