# Convert a List to String in Python

Tags: python

If have string stored as list under name

```
>>> name
['Aaron']
```

Using str(name) i get

```
>>> str(name)
"['Aaron']"
```

Output Required is

```
'Aaron'
```

Not

```
"['Aaron']"
```

Because my regular expression is not recognizing it as a string.

Answer (score 14):

To **join list of multiple elements (strings) in the list**, you may use [**`str.join`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) as

```
>>> name = ['Aaron', 'Sheron']

#    v  to join the words in the list using space ' '
>>> ' '.join(name)
'Aaron Sheron'
```

However, you are having a list of just one element. In order **to access the element at `0`th index**, you need to pass index as *(PS: `str.join` will work here too, but it is not required)*:

```
>>> name = ['Aaron']

#        v fetch `0`th element in the list
>>> name[0]
'Aaron'
```

Please also refer:

- [How to access List elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613131/how-to-access-list-elements)
- [Access list of items with list of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008533/access-list-of-items-with-list-of-indices)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use:

```
''.join(name)
```

`join` joins all elements of the list into one string.

Answer (score 3):

Already answered in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5618893/5611425)

```
print(''.join(name))
```